# Перенос тернарного оператора и вызываемых методов

Tags: c#, code-style

Какой способ переноса для тернарного оператора является наиболее общепринятым?

```
a = b ?
    c :
    d;

a = b
    ? c
    : d;
```

Аналогичный вопрос про вызываемые методы.

```
someObject.
   Foo();

someObject
  .Foo()
```

В качестве ответа меня бы вполне устроила ссылка на code style conventions какой-нибудь крупной компании, где фигурируют эти вопросы.

Comment: Как в C# не знаю, но в JavaScript'e общепринятая форма переноса тернарного оператора - вторая. Во втором случае, как мне кажется, однозначно - второй вариант, во всяком случае первого я практически нигде не видел

Comment: Когда то натыкался на статью где описаны около 6 стилей написания кода. Общепринятый, я так  понимаю это который чаще используют.Советую поискать статистику использования стилей или что то в этом направлении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Придерживаюсь второго варианта как в первом, так и во втором случае.
Врядли здесь можно найти "общепринятый" способ переноса. Каждый это решает сам, или придерживается правил, принятых в команде.

Answer (score 3):

1) Второе.

2) Второе.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант более привычно выглядит, т.к. ближе к естественной пунктуации английского языка (знак препинания в конце строки).

Второй вариант более эффективен с технической точки зрения. Вы можете в отладочных целях комментировать отдельные строки кода, не нарушая его синтаксической корректности, что было бы затруднительно, будь у Вас оператор в конце строки. Ну и само размещение оператора в начале строки просто нагляднее - там он заметнее.

Answer (score 1):

Если уж приходится переносить, то первый вариант это

```
a?
  b: c;
```

или (ну, совсем не влезает)

```
a?
  b:
  c;
```

Вообще, если выражение столь громоздко, что в две строки не помещается, то стоит подумать о функции.

Второй однозначно

```
obj
  .m();
```

Comment: ИМХО первый, если все-таки переносить:

     someVeryLongConditionTrololoOlolo
     ? doIfTrue
     : doIfFalse;

Comment: @avp, а если тернатрный оператор представлен не `?:`, а например всё теми же `if then else`? тогда 

    if a then
      b else 
      c;

выглядит крайне несуразно в отличии от

    if a 
       then b 
       else c;

Comment: @Spectre, на мой вкус вариант if then else надо переносить так

    if a then
       b
    else
       c

Вообще вопрос холиварный.